# Using variables with sed

Tags: linux, shell, variables, sed, console

I'm trying to delete a part of a file using sed in Linux (Ubuntu). Specifically, I want to delete the first lines of a log file until the first occurrence of the current system date (using the pattern '10 Jan 13').

So, I store the date in a variable

```
root@server:/# VAR_DATE=`date -R | cut -c6-11`
```

And after that, I use sed

```
root@server:/# cat log_file.txt | sed -n -e '/$VAR_DATE/,$p'
```

But it doesn't work. I've tried a lot of combinations with the same result:

```
root@server:/# cat log_file.txt | sed -n -e '/"$VAR_DATE"/,$p'
root@server:/# cat log_file.txt | sed -n -e '/"${VAR_DATE}"/,$p'
root@server:/# cat log_file.txt | sed -n -e "/$VAR_DATE/,$p"
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes so the variable `$vardate` gets expanded by the shell and escape the last `$` so it's not expanded by the shell `sed -n "/$vardate/,\$p" file`:

```
$ cat file
6 Jan 13
7 Jan 13
8 Jan 13
9 Jan 13
10 Jan 13
11 Jan 13
12 Jan 13
13 Jan 13

$ vardate="10 Jan 13"

$ sed -n "/$vardate/,\$p" file
10 Jan 13
11 Jan 13
12 Jan 13
13 Jan 13
```